# Find divisors of set of integers that divide to integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let there exist a finite set of integers $S$.

How would you find all $d$ where $d \in \mathbb{R} \land d \ge 1$ such that $\forall_{s \in S} \left( \frac{s}{d} = \text{floor} \left( \frac{s}{d} \right) \right)$?

Comment: the biggest $d$   is the $\gcd(s_1, s_2, ..., s_n)$   if $S$  is finite.

Comment: @WillJagy Ah, good point. I also updated the question to specify that the set is finite.

Comment: @Servaes This is not actually a homework problem. The original context is that I am making a graphical application where I wanted the window to be proportional to 1920 x 1080. I wanted to know what numbers I could divide both 1920 and 1080 by to get whole number window sizes. I decided to make the problem more general in my question, though.

Comment: @GigiBayte2 That's some useful context to provide in the question. Also missing (in my opinion) is your own progress on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notation that we'll use:

$[r] :=$ floor($r$),

$(n,m) = gcd(m,n)$

$n|s \iff \exists_{q \in {\bf Z}} : s=nq $

At first suppose you have only **one** $s$:

Since $[r] \leqslant r $, so $\frac{s}{d}$ should be integer, therefore $d$ must be rational.

Now suppose $d = \frac{n}{m}$, where $(n,m)=1$, so $\frac{s}{d} = \frac{ms}{n}$, that should be integer as stated, therefore $n|ms$.

Since $(m,n)=1$, we have $n|s$, so $n$ only can be chosen from divisors of $s$:

$$D = \{ d = \frac{n}{m} | n,m \in {\bf{Z}}, (n,m)=1, n|s \}$$

Now if you have many $s$, the restriction $n|s$, should be satisfied for all $s \in S$. And this is the reason of what @WillJagy said you: $ \bf gcd(s_1,...,s_n)$, simply say $gcd(S)$ So:

$$D = \{ d = \frac{n}{m} | n,m \in {\bf{Z}}, (n,m)=1, n|gcd(S) \}$$

Even the assumption of **Finitness of $\bf S$**, can be dropped, since $gcd(S) = 1$ is nothing to fear of (It can be occurs also with finite $S$)! Also Interesting infinite set exist, like all multiples of $2$, that has $gcd(S)>1$.

At end you can also forget of restriction $(m,n)=1$, it doesn't change your set, just you write less!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will have to analyze the mathematical notation to actually make sense of this answer (e.g. $[r] \le r$, $(n, m) = 1$, and $n \vert s$).

Comment: @GigiBayte2 I add some explanation, and I hope those will help you.